# Reports time out

Tags: reporting-services

Good day

I have problem that really puzzle me. I wrote a report in visual basic 2008 when I run it it works perfectly. When I copied the report to report sever and run it it works perfectly.

I coded my asp.net application and call the report on a small database with about 500 entries everything shows and doesn't time out.

Problem is when entries the report must show becomes more than 500 the report runs but it stop and just show nothing it is as if it times out. There is no error nothing just stops.

I have no idea what to do? Anyone with any advise please.

I have change in the report server web.config file this setting to longer like "30000"

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" />
```

Then on the report it self on server change the setting to never time out.

Then in the asp.net web config file change the timeout to "30000" but still when data to much the report just stop like I said no error no warning nothing it just stop and there is no info displaying so if anyone have any advise please assist.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior when one of the report parameters gets too long (= has too many options.)

Answer (score 1):

I would use SQL profiler to see what is being submitted to the database.  Take that query and run it in SSMS.  View the explain plan in SSMS.  This may let you know why the query is becoming so slow with the larger data.  I would also look at the report server logs - something will be in there.